# Почему программа аварийно завершается?

Tags: c++

```
{
    string str;
    int arr[30];
    int k = 0;

    cin >> str;

    for (int i = 0; str.length() - 1; i++) {
    if (str[i] == '+')
        arr[k++] = str[i]; // и тут сменил на arr[i++]???
    }

    for (int i = 0; str.length() - 1; i++) {
        cout << arr[i]; // сменил, но выводится огромное бессмысленное число
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Почему ввожу 1 + 2, он должен поместить, вроде, '+' в массив и вывести, но он аварийно завершает программу. В чем проблема? Какую ужасную ошибку я тут вытворяю и не замечаю?

Comment: условие вы добавили когда завершать циклы?

i <= str.length() - 1
или
i <= str.size() - 1

Comment: for(int i = 0; str.length() - 1; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[k];
    }

Это что за фигня?

Comment: @manking упс! Точно! Тупая ошибка. А щас вот выводит 000 в качестве ответа на пример 1 + 2, а должен + вывести. Что не то?

Comment: Может где

cout << arr[k];
 поставить i

cout << arr[i];

Comment: @manking код сменил и добавил комментарии. Смотрите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::string str = "1 + 2";
char arr[30];
int k = 0;

for (int i = 0; i <= str.size() - 1; i++)
{
if (str[i] == '+')
{
arr[k] = str[i]; 
k++;
}
}

for (int i = 0; i <= k - 1; i++)
{
std::cout << "\n" << arr[i];
}
```

Comment: Ерунда, конечно, но я бы писал

    for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
     и
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)

Может мне просто лень лишние символы читать?

Comment: Просто -1 напоминает, что значение size() больше чем последний индекс массива.

Собственно это вообще не важно, главное не использовать стиль с !=, чтобы не проскочить цикл при изменении i если вдруг нужно что то вроде i+=2.

Comment: @manking, странный стиль, откуда он взялся?

Comment: Какой именно <= !=?

Comment: @manking,  оба.

Comment: Их повсеместно используют. 
В различных библиотеках попадается <=.
А != в stl для итераторов всегда применяется.

Странным здесь было бы внутри цикла ставить проверку и делать break;

Comment: @manking, в одном месте пишете

     главное не использовать стиль с !=

а потом

     А != в stl для итераторов всегда применяется

Собственно, странным то кажется не само по себе '<=', а совет связывать `<=` с выражением `str.size() - 1`.

И аргументация этого какая-то странная, советы для "хронически невнимательных", что ли.